# PHP Find Hashtags In String And Insert Into Database

Tags: php

I want to find all hashtags from a string and insert them into a table (sql).

```
$string = "hello #hashtag_1 bla bla #hashtag_2";
```

I don't have idea how to do this. Any ideas?

```
    function getHashtags($string) {  
    $hashtags= FALSE;  
    preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/u", $string, $matches);  
    if ($matches) {
        $hashtagsArray = array_count_values($matches[0]);
        $hashtags = array_keys($hashtagsArray);
    }
    return $hashtags;
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well when you return `$hashtags`, it is returned as an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => #hashtag_1
    [1] => #hashtag_2
)
```

You need to combine the array into a string. Use this as your `getHashtags()` function (I chose to have it be comma separated but you can choose other delimiters)

```
function getHashtags($string) {  
    $hashtags = FALSE;  
    preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/u", $string, $matches);  
    if ($matches) {
        $hashtags = implode(",", $matches[0]);
    }
    return $hashtags;
}
```

`$hashtags` would return `#hashtag_1,#hashtag_2` 
and then your `$sql_query` should change to

```
$sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO hashtags VALUES('" . getHashtags($string) . "')")
```

Also be sure to add a check if `$hashtags != FALSE` so it only inserts into database if there is a hashtag

So here is the full code:

```
function getHashtags($string) {  
    $hashtags = FALSE;  
    preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/u", $string, $matches);  
    if ($matches) {
        $hashtags = implode(",", $matches[0]);
    }
    return $hashtags;
}

$hashtags = getHashtags($string);
if($hashtags != FALSE) {
    $sql_query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO hashtags VALUES('" . $hashtags . "')")
}
```

Comment: Check my latest edit. I add a check if `$hashtags != FALSE`